# File Manipulation on AmazonS3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

The download content we provide for our customers needs some slight modifications to it prior to delivering it to the customer.  This is preventing us from using AmazonS3 for storage.  Does Amazon provide any kind of service that allows someone to manipulate data directly on AmazonS3?  Specifically using Java technology.

Comment: to understand, you would like to change an S3 file in some way, without downloading and re-uploading it? would it be a one time operation or you want to personalise this download just in time, so each customer gets something different?

Comment: They are PDF files and I need to stamp the footer each time they are downloaded, with customer info.

Comment: The reason I can't store a PDF per customer is because they change often.  So our system would constantly be uploading new revisions on a daily basis.  And that isn't optimal, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to process your files on the fly to add a footer each time a file is downloaded, S3 is not for you. You can use for backup, but you need to process them with an application server.

If you use EC2, it may be viable to download the file from S3 to EC2 and serve it. It will still be faster to have a local copy though.